# Java Grid Layout wrong Button size and wrong location

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

i got a problem with a Java Swing Application.

[image]

My Code:

```
public class AdminToken extends JFrame {


VirtualServer server;

@Override
public Container getContentPane() {
    return super.getContentPane();
}

public AdminToken(VirtualServer server)
{
    this.server = server;
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setupGUI();
   setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

}
void setupGUI()
{

    setTitle("Token Management Server: " + server.getName() );
    setSize(576,528);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
    LoginForm.api.selectVirtualServer(server);
    for( final PrivilegeKey tokens  : LoginForm.api.getPrivilegeKeys()) {

        final JLabel label =  new JLabel(tokens.getToken() + "   " + tokens.getGroupId() + "   " +  "\n");

        panel.add(label);
        JButton button = new JButton("Löschen");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                LoginForm.api.deletePrivilegeKey(tokens.getToken());
                panel.remove(label);
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(87,25));
        panel.add(button);

    }
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (panel,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    add(scrollPane);

    LoginForm.api.selectVirtualServerById(LoginForm.vServerId);
}
```

The Tokens should be displayed like this:

Token1 Button Delete \n

Token 2 Button Delete \n

Token 3 Button Delete \n
And so one

And i also can't change the size of my buttons in another JFrame:

[image]

The Code:

```
public class TsServerOverview extends JFrame {


@Override
public Container getContentPane() {
    return super.getContentPane();
}

public TsServerOverview()
{
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setupGUI();
    setLayout(new GridLayout());

}
void setupGUI()
{

    setTitle("Ts3Query Server Oveview");
    setSize(576,528);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));
    for( final VirtualServer servers : LoginForm.api.getVirtualServers()) {

        final int id = servers.getId();
       panel.add(new JLabel(servers.getId() + "    " + servers.getName() + "   " + servers.getClientsOnline() + "/" + servers.getMaxClients() + "\n"));
       JButton button = new JButton("Konsole öffnen");

        JButton showchannels = new JButton("Channel-Liste");
        JButton tokenmanagement = new JButton("Token Management");
        showchannels.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));
       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               new GUIConsole(servers);
           }
       });
       showchannels.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               new ChannelList(servers);
           }
       });
       tokenmanagement.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               new AdminToken(servers);
           }
       });
       tokenmanagement.setVisible(true);
        button.setVisible(true);
        showchannels.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(showchannels);

       panel.add(button);
       panel.add(tokenmanagement);

    }
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (panel,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    add(scrollPane);
}
```

That should also be displayed like this:

Server1 3/32 Online Start Stop Console \n

Server2 3/32 Offline Start Stop Console \n

Server3 3/32 Online Start Stop Console

**The Buttons should be next to the Server Line.**

It would be nice if someone could help me with my code.

Comment: Please ask one such question in a post. For quick and eficient help, please post [mcve]

Comment: The issue is the way you are using a GridLayout.  In the first case you created a grid with GridLayout(5,1) meaning 5 rows, 1 column.  Notice how you created a JPanel and with that layout and added it to the JFrame then changed the JFrame's layout to the same.  You need to set your  frame's layout manager before you add the JScrollPane and give you JPanel more columns.

Comment: The second question is similar. A GridLayout will fill the entirety of the available space and stretch the added children to fill in all the space in the GridCell.  For total control you can use GridBagLayout, but  combinations of other layout managers like Box will work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AdminToken extends JFrame {   
VirtualServer server;

@Override
public Container getContentPane() {
    return super.getContentPane();
}
```

Remove everything which is not needed to demonstrate the issue. That includes `VirtualServer`

```
public AdminToken(VirtualServer server)
{
    this.server = server;
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setupGUI();
   setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
}
```

`getContentPane().setLayout` and `setLayout` are essentially the same. No use of setting it twice. Avoid null layout managers.

```
void setupGUI()
{ 
    setTitle("Token Management Server: " + server.getName() );
    setSize(576,528);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
```

`setTitle` is not needed to demonstrate the issue. No need to set size. Set preferred sizes when applicable and let the layout manager do the layout. `setResizable(true)` is the default. The same applies to `button.setVisible(true);` 
You typically want `setVisible(true);` at the end.

```
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
```

By `new GridLayout(5,1)` you set the grid to have 5 row. If you add more it messes up the layout. From java doc:

> rows - the rows, with the value zero meaning any number of rows.

```
    LoginForm.api.selectVirtualServer(server);
    for( final PrivilegeKey tokens  : LoginForm.api.getPrivilegeKeys()) {

        final JLabel label =  new JLabel(tokens.getToken() + "   " + tokens.getGroupId() + "   " +  "\n");

        panel.add(label);
        JButton button = new JButton("Löschen");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                LoginForm.api.deletePrivilegeKey(tokens.getToken());
                panel.remove(label);
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(87,25));
        panel.add(button);

    }
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (panel,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    add(scrollPane);

    LoginForm.api.selectVirtualServerById(LoginForm.vServerId);
}
```

Here is [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what I think you are tying to achieve:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AdminToken extends JFrame {

    public AdminToken()
    {
        setupGUI();
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        pack();
    }
    void setupGUI() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));

        for(int row =0; row < 6; row++ ) {
            panel.add(new JLabel("Label "+row));
            panel.add(new JButton("Delete"));
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (panel);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new AdminToken() );
    }
}
```